# sql & inner join

Tags: sql

I'm having a challenge with INNER JOIN in BigQuery.
When trying to run this, I get following error message:

> Unrecognized name: employees at [8:2]’ with line 8 being
> employees.department_id =departments.department_id

```
SELECT 
 name, role, department_id
FROM
`dataanalysis001.employee_data.employees`
 INNER JOIN
 `dataanalysis001.employee_data.departments` 
 ON
 employees.department_id =departments.department_id
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 5):

You need to either use the fully qualified name for a table every time you use it or, preferably, alias it and use the alias.

so either:

```
SELECT 
 name, role, department_id
FROM
`dataanalysis001.employee_data.employees`
 INNER JOIN
 `dataanalysis001.employee_data.departments` 
 ON dataanalysis001.employee_data.employees.department_id 
= dataanalysis001.employee_data.departments.department_id
```

or

```
SELECT 
 name, role, department_id
FROM
`dataanalysis001.employee_data.employees` emp
 INNER JOIN
 `dataanalysis001.employee_data.departments` dep
 ON emp.department_id = dep.department_id
```

Answer (score 2):

By on you usually compare a foreign key with a primary key

```
 ON
 employees.department_id =departments.id
```

But if it's the database structure then is it OK.
She is an example of an inner join

```
SELECT Authors.AuthorID, Books.name, Books.date
```

FROM Authors
INNER JOIN Books ON Authors.BookId=Books.id;

```
  SELECT 
d.name, e.role, e.department_id
FROM
`dataanalysis001.employee_data.employees` as e
 INNER JOIN
 `dataanalysis001.employee_data.departments` as d
 ON
 e.department_id = d.department_id;
```